# Flutetr return widget when its maybe can be null and getting error

Tags: flutter, dart

In optional our constructor of class we have:

```dart
final Widget? errorScreen;
const NoNetwork({Key? key, this.errorScreen}) : super(key: key);
```

and in `build` method i want to check if its not null, `widget.errorScreen` should be return otherwise should be return `Scaffold`:

```dart
class _NoNetworkState extends State<NoNetwork> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.errorScreen == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
             ///
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return widget.errorScreen;
    }
  }
}
```

as `errorScreen` can be null and we used `?` wildcard for that, i get this error:

> A value of type 'Widget?' can't be returned from the method 'build'
> because it has a return type of 'Widget'.

simplified of using `NoNetwork` class :

```dart
class NetworkSensitive extends StatelessWidget {
  ///

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///
    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityStatus.WiFi) {
      return child;
    }

    ///

    return const NoNetwork();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add ! at the end

```
return widget.errorScreen!;
```

This way you are indicating that is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try something like that:

```
class _NoNetworkState extends State<NoNetwork> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.errorScreen == null) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
             ///
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return widget.errorScreen ?? Container();
    }
  }
}
```